# Listivew first global position change during orientation

Tags: android, listview

In my project I am using quick popup in `ListView`, it support for 7 inch and 10 inch tablet, when i click `ListView`, the popup is displayed, when I change orientation the `ListView` changes orientation. I used the code `onConfigurationChanged` like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    quickActionView.dismiss();

    Log.d("Global_View", "" + views);
    Log.d("Global_Position", "" + globalPosition);

    listprimary.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            listprimary.smoothScrollToPosition(globalPosition);

            int firstVisibleRow = listprimary.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PLANNED_SCHEDULE, "firstVisibleRow" + firstVisibleRow);

            int lastVisibleRow = listprimary.getLastVisiblePosition();

            Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PLANNED_SCHEDULE, "lastVisibleRow" + lastVisibleRow);

            int output = firstVisibleRow + lastVisibleRow;

            Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PLANNED_SCHEDULE, "Output" + output);

            int check = globalPosition - output;

            Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PLANNED_SCHEDULE, "Check" + check);

            View selectedView = listprimary.getChildAt(check);

            Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PLANNED_SCHEDULE, "SelectionView" + selectedView);

            if (selectedView != null) {

                Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PLANNED_SCHEDULE, "SelectedView" + selectedView);

                initializePopUp(selectedView);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: But i have problem in getFirstVisiblePosition(); when i change orientation

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is as its not clear from your question

Comment: @Ryan Dansie When i change landscape mode, the position starting 0-8 but the actual position is 7-12

Comment: Formatted code to be consistent and removed unneeded, commented out code. Also, look into saving activity instance variables for orientation state change.  You need to persist the visibility after orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what your question is... But if you change your orientation your activity will restart. That means, that onCreate and so on will be called again. -> If you init you listView and your adapter there, the listView and the adapter are having a new instance! ... Make sure, that you save adapterInstance and set the instance for the list view again! ... Otherwise you need to save the current position and get get them from `savedInstanceState` in your onCreate to reset the position

Add code, where you init your list view for more help

Comment: listprimary.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                initializePopUp(view);
                globalPosition = position;
                views = view;

            }
        });

Comment: I mean your onCreate and your code, where you do something like this: "ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);" and "listView.setAdapter(new Adapter());" 

And PLEASE, do not paste it here.. -> Edit your question